# Chromecast stuck at 0 position when seek at start of video

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I have an android app. All works fine, but sometimes I send to chromecast action "seek to 0" it stuck at 0 position of video. In chrome cast console I see the loop of `time=0`:

[image]

Have someone seen this problem? Why it can be?

Answer (score 2):

I can only offer you a workaround...

I have faced similar issues with Chromecast. From my searches these stalling issues are caused by bugs in the Google cast library mostly related to particular streams. Getting more information about these issues I found to be difficult. You should check if you are getting any:

> "[cast.player.api.Player] playback stalled in buffered region"

warnings as it is often logged prior to the seek position being stuck while endlessly buffering.

A quick fix for the issue is to call `reload()` on your `cast.player.api.Player` instance in your receiver app either when detecting multiple "stalled" events on the video element or even just after loading a new stream. This will reload the media player at the current playing position. More info here [cast.player.api.Player#reload](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/cast.player.api.Player#reload)

Comment: So I should download player and fix it there, then host it by myself?

Comment: @inferus-vv Unfortunately it may be the only "easy" solution to host your own custom receiver to apply these kind of workarounds. You don't need to change player code specifically, default receiver is more of a view controller.

If you're casting a lot of different content from various sources you may find yourself needing to implement quite a few workarounds in a custom receiver. I needed to implement "reload()" call on the first "onBuffering_" event callback... Not pretty but but it works like a charm.

You could always host it out on google drive to make it easier...